# Does dominate monster spell continues working if the creature caster is 60 feet away or more?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I was planning on running Waterdeep Dragon Heist for my party and i have a doubt.
In chapter I page 28 a mindflayer cast [Dominate monster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-monster) on any player or party member who tries to intervene in his escape.
Does this spell keeps working even if he is more than 60 feets away from the target?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and maybe you can visit the [help] in case you need any guidance for posting question and answer here. Happy gaming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes, it keeps working.

The spell description states (emphasis mine):

> While the creature is charmed, you have a telepathic link with it **as long as the two of you are on the same plane of existence**.

The telepathic link lasts while the caster and the target are on the same plane: if the target is 60 ft away from the caster *and* it is on the same plane of existence, hence the spell is still active. There is no mention about being more than 60 ft away from the caster: for this spell, the range is important at casting time.

Each time the target receives damage, they can repeat the saving throw: in case of success the spell ends, as described in the text.

> Each time the target takes damage, it makes a new Wisdom saving throw against the spell. If the saving throw succeeds, the spell ends.

This spell exactly follows the general [rules for spell range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range):

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise.

---

As a counterexample, consider the [*Mage Hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mage-hand) cantrip, that explicit states what happen outside specific range (emphasis mine):

> A spectral, floating hand appears at a point you choose within range. The hand lasts for the duration or until you dismiss it as an action. **The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you** or if you cast this spell again.

Comment: You ought to mention the [rules for spell range](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Range) that state: "Once a spell is cast, its effects aren't limited by its range, unless the spell's description says otherwise."

Comment: @ThomasMarkov You're right, added!